# listener.AcceptTcpClient() doesn't work in c# and works in Java

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I have a socket listener application implemented in Java, and works fine

C# Code:

```
        IPAddress serverAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(serverAddress, 1234);
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(client.ReceiveBufferSize));
            string request = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine(request);
        }
```

White it works fine in Java:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
Socket socket = server.accept();
```

In java a new client connection started, and I managed to read data. While in C# it didn't create any TcpClient at all.

Please Help!

Comment: What does you client code look like that connects to this server?

Comment: @Lorek it is a GPRS Device

Comment: Try using IPAddress.Any instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I am new to C#, can you elaborate

Comment: `TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);`

Comment: You are the best man :D, it works. Can you help me understand why? what is the different from using "127.0.0.1"

Comment: When you use "127.0.0.1" you are binding the server socket to the loopback address.  Only clients on the same machine are able to communicate with servers that use the loopback IP.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't expect it would be that quick. please add an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your TcpLister initialization with this:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
```

When you use "127.0.0.1" you are binding the server socket to the loopback address. Only clients on the same machine are able to communicate with servers that use the loopback IP.